# Show the number of table rows of a table in a h1 headline

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to show the total number of table rows in a h1 headline.

I have a table in this format:

```
<table class="sortable" align="center" id="sortabletable" style="text-align:center;"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>X</th> 
    <th>Y</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>A</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>B</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>C</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

</tbody> 
</table>
```

This is the headline where I would like to show the number of table rows, which would be 4 (including headers) for the example table mentioned previously:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Headline (X nr of table rows)</h1>
```

I have found this javascript and several others to calculate the number of rows, but I don't know how to show the number in the headline.

```
<script language="javascript">
var rowCount = document.getElementById('sortabletable').rows.length;
</script>
```

Comment: None of [these 537000 articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=dom+manipulation+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=qchpVY-RC8u3Ub-DgMgF) answered your question?

Comment: Well, doing some research before asking is highly appreciated at SO, actually it's [mandatory](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, please keep the way you've originally counted the rows (and ... me brilliant????).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('sortabletable').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
    
document.getElementById('row_count').innerHTML = 'Headline ('+ rows +' nr of table rows)';
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;" id="row_count">Headline (X nr of table rows)</h1>
```

Comment: Problem is not in calculating, problem in showing this number.

Comment: Actually, this is a great solution. I have to admit that my js knowledge is lacking, so the javascript breakdown is welcomed. 

I did do several searches on google before posting, but I apologize if anyone thought it was a stupid question. Either way, thanks @Avinash!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<h1 id="numberOfRows">
</h1>
```

JavaScript

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

document.getElementById("numberOfRows").innerHTML = "Number of rows" + rows;
```

Comment: Hello, @AnchovyLegend, I'm terribly sorry for the late reply, but thank you for the code. I have tested it, and it works when the h1 title and table is on the same file.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = rows;
```

Though better to give your `h1` an `id` and use:

```
document.getElementById('THE_ID').innerHTML = rows;`
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Samurai. You are correct, but since the four answers are relatively similar, I can only choose one answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need some means by which you can refer to the relevant `<h1>` element:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Headline (X nr of table rows)</h1>
```

Given that it's the first, and should be the *only*, `<h1>` you can use either:

```
document.querySelector('h1');
```

Or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
```

Which leads to:

```
document.querySelector('h1').textContent = 'Headline (' + rowcount+ ' nr of table rows)';
```

```js
var rowcount = document.getElementById('sortabletable').rows.length;
document.querySelector('h1').textContent = 'Headline (' + rowcount+ ' nr of table rows)';
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<table class="sortable" align="center" id="sortabletable" style="text-align:center;"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>X</th> 
    <th>Y</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>A</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>B</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>C</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

</tbody> 
</table>
```

Or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent = 'Headline (' + rowcount + ' nr of table rows)';
```

```js
var rowcount = document.getElementById('sortabletable').rows.length;
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent = 'Headline (' + rowcount+ ' nr of table rows)';
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<table class="sortable" align="center" id="sortabletable" style="text-align:center;"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>X</th> 
    <th>Y</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>A</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>B</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>C</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

</tbody> 
</table>
```

Or, using just CSS:

```
body {
  counter-reset: rowCount;
}
#sortabletable tr {
  counter-increment: rowCount;
}
#count::before {
  content: ' (' counter(rowCount) ')';
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: rowCount;
}
#sortabletable tr {
  counter-increment: rowCount;
}
#count::before {
  content: ' (' counter(rowCount) ')';
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable" align="center" id="sortabletable" style="text-align:center;"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>X</th> 
    <th>Y</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>A</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>B</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>C</p>
      <p>
        <a href="URL" title="TEXT" target="_blank">
        <img src="image URL" width="" height="" alt="Alt Text">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td> 
  <td>Date</td> 
</tr>

</tbody> 
</table>
<h1>Headline <span id="count"></span></h1>
```

Though, unfortunately, the CSS approach can only work if the `<h1>` element appears after the `<table>` (to allow the counter to increment before we apply its results in the displaying element).

Comment: Hello, @David, thank you for mentioning several possibilities on how to get the table row number in a h1 title.